# How to make javascript cookie secure. I have tried the regex for securing the url and cookie value but no one is working

Tags: javascript

This is my cookie code.

```
var campaignId ="someCookieValue";
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (365*24*60*60*1000));   // SET COOKIE EXPIRY TO 365 days.
var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = 'campaignId='+ campaignId + "; Domain="+ document.domain + "; path=/; " + expires;
document.cookie = 'sourceUrl='+ window.location.href + ";" + expires;
```

**Tried this for validating**

```
var campaignId ="someCookieValue";  
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (365*24*60*60*1000));   // SET COOKIE EXPIRY TO 365 days.
var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
var value = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.:]*$/);
if(value.test(campaignId))
    document.cookie = 'campaignId='+ campaignId + "; Domain="+ document.domain + "; path=/; " + expires;
var expression =/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
var pattern = new RegExp(expression);
var cookieValue = window.location.href;
if(cookieValue){
    if(value.test(cookieValue)) {
        cookieValue = encodeURIComponent(cookieValue);
        document.cookie = 'sourceUrl='+ cookieValue + ";" + expires;
    }
}
```

I'm getting issue in fortify scan on `document.cookie` like the method `lambda()` in `main.js` includes unvalidated data in an HTTP cookie on line 486. This enables Cookie manipulation attacks and can lead to other HTTP Response header manipulation attacks like: `cache-poisoning`, `cross-site scripting`, `cross-user defacement`, `page hijacking` or `open redirect`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't get it

Comment: I'm getting issue in fortify scan on document.cookie like  

The method lambda() in main.js includes unvalidated data in an HTTP cookie on line 486. This enables Cookie manipulation attacks and can lead to other

Comment: so i tried to validate it by regex

Comment: "so i tried to validate it by regex"   I don't think that's what fortify is talking about. Try to make it tamper-proof.

Comment: Looking over the [OWASP article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Session_Management_Schema_(OWASP-SM-001)) wouldn't it be easier to simply encrypt the cookies content?

Comment: Sorry for "not an answer" but if you need a secure way to use cookie - best option is not to invent a wheel. You can use http only cookies (if you don't need to access them from js) or you can use external libraries that encrypt them for you (just an example https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-encrypter)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I encripted my cookie values by an external cryptoJs and fortify scan issue resolved.

```
var campaignId ="someCookieValue";
    var mySecret ="mysecret";
    var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (365*24*60*60*1000));   // SET COOKIE EXPIRY TO 365 days.
            var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
            var mySecret ="mysecret";
            var cookieValue = window.location.href;
            //Here I added encryption
            campaignId = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(campaignId, mySecret);
            cookieValue = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(cookieValue, mySecret); //end
            document.cookie = 'campaignId='+ campaignId + "; Domain="+ document.domain + "; path=/; " + expires;
            document.cookie = 'sourceUrl='+ cookieValue + ";" + expires;
```